# How to send updated long/lat to server in android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my application i want to get the updated location of the mobile user and i want to send it to the server continuously after periodic interval of certain time or after the user travels certain(say 500 meter) distance.I need these things to be done in backgroung.I know for this i have to implement service class. But I am not getting exactly how to do this.I did some work on that.
Can anybody please help me in this issue.
I did following things in the service class.

```
public class BackGroundService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    public static final String Tag = BackGroundService.class.getName();
    LocationManager myLocationManager;
    Location myLocation;
    LocationListener myLocationListener;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void OnCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(Tag, "Service Started");

        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);

        String locationProvider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000*60*5, 500, myLocationListener);
        myLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);


    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        longitude = location.getLongitude(); 
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(Tag, "Provider is disabled");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(Tag, "Location Provider is enabled");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

From here I want know how can i get current lat/long of user and send it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for my question is.......

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    final LocationManager mlocmag = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener mlocList = new MyLocationList();
    final Location loc = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    UpdateWithNewLocation(loc); // This method is used to get updated location. 
    mlocmag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocList);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
 private void UpdateWithNewLocation(final Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(loc!= null)
        {
        final double lat =loc.getLatitude(); // Updated lat
        final double Long = loc.getLongitude(); // Updated long


        ConnectMySQL obj = new ConnectMySQL();
        obj.call(lat,Long); // Call this method when location is updated and save the data.

        }

        else 
        {
            String latLongStr = "No lat and longitude found";
              Toast.makeText(this, "Your location is "+latLongStr ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
    public class MyLocationList implements LocationListener
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UpdateWithNewLocation(arg0);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS Disable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```